# Suspect and doubt + negative sentence

Tags: vocabulary

Could you tell me the difference in meaning between

> I suspect he did not do it

and

> I doubt he did not do it

?

Answer (score 1):

Suspect and doubt are *antonyms*, they mean the opposite things, so in order for the sentences to have the same meaning, the negative on one of the sentences needs to be flipped.

Ie.

> I suspect that he did not do it.

means the same as

> I doubt that he did it.

Similarly:

> I suspect that he did it.

means the same as

> I doubt that he did not do it.

But this last sentence is very clumsy and confusing because of the double negative, it would be better to say

> I doubt that he is innocent.

Answer (score 1):

*Suspecting* and *doubting* are opposite concepts.

1) "I think [that] he did it":

> I suspect [that] he did it
>
> I don't doubt [that] he did it

2) "I don't think [that] he did it":

> I suspect [that] he did not do it
>
> I doubt [that] he did it

You may have noticed that the negative form of each verb differs in how it is constructed:

> I suspect [that] he did not...
>
> I don't doubt [that] he...

(Words in square brackets are optional -- the inclusion of 'that' makes the sentence sound slightly more formal.)

Comment: As a none native English speaker I have always confused myself with the usage of suspect. After you post, I believe I will remember it.